# How to return unknown value using known value from same column in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a form which submits email address, name and image plus a few more fields. All the submissions are stored in the same column named sentValue but each form field's unique name is in column formField.

First time submissions require all fields but returning users only need to enter their email and the form then returns only the image upload because it found the email address in the DB.

I want to use the known value of fieldname 'email' to return it's matching 'name' value from fieldname 'name' and print to the page with just the image upload.

This is what it is without correct logic and I have attempted numerous other formats and SQL syntax

```
SELECT sentValue AS name FROM tbl_submission 
WHERE formID='2' AND formField='name' 
AND formField='email' AND sentValue='smit@home.com'
return $query;
```

What is the correct SQL query to achieve my goal?

@Matt this is the structure
tbl_submission
formID - because multiple forms will post to the table and each has an ID
formSubsID - each field's data gets an ID on DB entry
formField - stores the unique name of each field
sentValue - stores the value of each field as entered by the user

```
|formID|formSubsID|formField|sentValue|
|  1   |   1      | name    | mike    |
|  1   |   1      | email   |mi@hom.us|
|  1   |   1      | image   |img.jpg  |
|  2   |   34     | image   |new.jpg  |
```

The first page the user sees has a form with a single email text field. The entry is not stored in the DB but the formID 1 in the DB is queried on submission to see if the entered email already exists. If not, then form with ID 1 showing all required fields is returned.

If the query returns true that the email is in the DB, yet a different form with ID 2 is returned which only displays a single image upload field and the image is stored in the same sentValue col. On this page is where I want the name associated with the found email, to be printed.

Comment: `... WHERE email='user_input' `

Comment: do you mean this: ** You just want to have one column and add some of your field on it? for example add email, name and address just on one column in MySQL** am I right?

Comment: I'm a little confused, all values are saved in one column but form fields are saved in others?  Can you include what your data would ideally look like?

Comment: @Dagon That was one of the many methods I tried before posting here

Comment: @Kermani I have 4 columns in one table and my efforts are focused on the 2 mentioned. sentValue collects the submissions and formField stores all the field names

Comment: @Matt See the edit in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to find a possible name with the same formSubsID as the email 'mi@hom.us'. You can do this using a simple LEFT JOIN, since the name may possibly not exist;

```
SELECT name.sentValue AS name 
FROM tbl_submission email
LEFT JOIN tbl_submission name 
  ON email.formSubsID = name.formSubsID AND name.formfield = 'name'
WHERE email.formfield = 'email' AND email.sentValue = 'mi@hom.us'
```

This will return the name, or NULL if no name exists. If you instead want no result at all if the name doesn't exist, you can just change the LEFT JOIN for a regular JOIN.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dfea/3).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it returns just the first name from the column and not the one associated with the email

Comment: @KumarSara Changed the Query to use formSubsID as the matching criteria, and changed the SQLfiddle to match your sample data.

Comment: the change did work perfectly. You are quite the SQL genius, Many thanks for the instruction.